# Error using edit user for devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have the following error when I try to edit the user's profile using devise. I am trying to allow user to edit his profile without password(Facebook login)

> The action 'update' could not be found for
>   Users::RegistrationsController

My registrations controller looks like:

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters

  protected

  # my custom fields are :name, :heard_how
  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) do |u|
      u.permit(:name, 
        :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
    end
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) do |u|
      u.permit(:name,
        :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password)
    end
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find(current_user.id)

    successfully_updated = if needs_password?(@user, params)
      @user.update_with_password(params[:user])
    else
      # remove the virtual current_password attribute update_without_password
      # doesn't know how to ignore it
      params[:user].delete(:current_password)
      @user.update_without_password(params[:user])
    end

    if successfully_updated
      set_flash_message :notice, :updated
      # Sign in the user bypassing validation in case his password changed
      sign_in @user, :bypass => true
      redirect_to after_update_path_for(@user)
    else
      render "edit"
    end
  end

  private

  # check if we need password to update user data
  # ie if password or email was changed
  # extend this as needed
  def needs_password?(user, params)
    user.email != params[:user][:email] ||
      params[:user][:password].present?
  end

end
```

And my route:

```
  devise_for :users, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "users/omniauth_callbacks",
  :registrations => "users/registrations"  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `update` method is not a public method of your class. By definition, only public methods of a Controller are called actions. To resolve this, move its definition above the `protected` keyword on line 5 like this:

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters

  # Now update is an action.    
  def update
    @user = User.find(current_user.id)

    successfully_updated = if needs_password?(@user, params)
      @user.update_with_password(params[:user])
    else
      # remove the virtual current_password attribute update_without_password
      # doesn't know how to ignore it
      params[:user].delete(:current_password)
      @user.update_without_password(params[:user])
    end

    if successfully_updated
      set_flash_message :notice, :updated
      # Sign in the user bypassing validation in case his password changed
      sign_in @user, :bypass => true
      redirect_to after_update_path_for(@user)
    else
      render "edit"
    end
  end

  protected
  #protected methods go here before the private keyword

  private
  # private methods go here
end
```